# NYtimes API, python

Tags: python, api

Hi I want to get all the information after 'title' from NYtimes API, here is my code

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from json import loads
import codecs
import time

def call_the_articles():
    url = "http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v1/article?query=US&facets=POLITICS&api-key=##"
    return loads(urlopen(url).read())

articles = call_the_articles()

if __name__ == '__main__':


    for story in articles("results"):
        print story['title'].encode('ascii', 'replace')
```

But when I run in terminal, the error coming out like:

```
File "NYtimes.py", line 10, in <module>
    articles = call_the_articles()
  File "NYtimes.py", line 8, in call_the_articles
    return loads(urlopen(url).read())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 406, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 444, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 527, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

How to solve the problem?

Comment: In your url, you made the api key `##` instead of some string. Perhaps that might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect what you want is:

```
url = "http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v1/article?format=json&query=US+des_facet%3A%5BPOLITICS+AND+GOVERNMENT%5D&api-key=##
```

There are a couple of things going on to cause a bad request:

1.) You're using the `facets` keyword incorrectly. From the [Times API developer docs on facets](http://developer.nytimes.com/docs/read/article_search_api#h3-facets-working):

> Facets can be thought of as search "perspectives." With facets, you can look at search results from different perspectives, and you can approach your search queries from different angles. Each facet can be seen as representing a property or characteristic of Times article data.
>
> Facets can reveal points of commonality and distinction that are not immediately apparent. For example, two articles with the word "bicycle" in the title may have two very different nytd_section_facet (NYTimes.com section) values: "Movies" and "Health." Similarly, two articles that discuss seemingly disparate topics, such as cloud computing and auto shows, may share a des_facet (descriptive subject term) value: "NEW MODELS, DESIGN AND PRODUCTS."

2.)You need to URLEncode your query when you send it through urlopen().

Also, `articles` will be a dict, so you'll want to get the articles out using `[]`:

```
for story in articles["results"]:
```

If the query here is not exactly what you want, NYT has a tool that allows you to play with constructing your queries: [NYT API Request Tool](http://prototype.nytimes.com/gst/apitool/index.html?api_id=0&request_id=0&query=US%20des_facet:%5BPOLITICS%20AND%20GOVERNMENT%5D&facets=&begin_date=&fields=&offset=&rank=&resp_format=json&perform_request=Make%20Request&use_pp=on).